# Github v3 API get all organizations more than 100

Tags: github, pagination, github-api, http-get, github-organizations

I am trying to get all organization items through http://host/api/v3/organizations?page=2&per_page=100

The default size seems like 30, and 100 seems like the max limit per request.
But above link still only returns the first 100 items, i.e, not 101-200th

I also tried http:host//api/v3/organizations?page=2
No matter which page I set, it only returns the first 30 items.

How can I get the entire list of organization items please? Please help. Appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Github API reference for listing organizations](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/#list-all-organizations) :

> Note: Pagination is powered exclusively by the since parameter. Use
>   the [Link header](https://developer.github.com/v3/#link-header) to get the URL for the next page of organizations.

For instance checking the 2nd page using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) :

```bash
curl -I "https://api.github.com/organizations"
```

gives the following link header :

```
Link: <https://api.github.com/organizations?since=3043>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/organizations{?since}>; rel="first"
```

So the next page will be https://api.github.com/organizations?since=3043

For each request you would check this header to get the next url to hit