# $http.get upon previous returned response

Tags: asynchronous, recursion, promise, http-get

my brain drained... Help please.

Background is about [Github v3 API get all organizations more than 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703708/github-v3-api-get-all-organizations-more-than-100)  I am continue working using the answer.

1. Pass http://host.com/api/v3/organizations?page=1&per_page=100 the response header contains a link of `<http://host.otpp.com/api/v3/organizations?page=1&per_page=100&since=318>; rel="next", <http://host.com/api/v3/organizations{?since}>; rel="first"`
2. so now I continue to extract 318 and use http://host.com/api/v3/organizations?page=1&per_page=100&since=318 and now the response header contains link of `"<http://host.com/api/v3/organizations?page=1&per_page=100&since=560>; rel="next", <http://github.host.com/api/v3/organizations{?since}>; rel="first""`
3. Extract 560 and Use "http://github.host.com/api/v3/organizations?page=1&per_page=100&since=560". The response header is `"<http://github.host.com/api/v3/organizations{?since}>; rel="first"`
4. Since step 3 does not have "next", I know that's the last page.

Here is my code:

```
function loadAll($scope, $http) {
    var data = [];
    $http.get(HostgitAPIURL + "organizations?page=1&per_page=100").then(
        function(res) {
             data.push(res.data);
             var link = parse_link_header(res.headers()['link']);
             // links[name]=url 

             while ("next" in link) {
                $http.get(link[name]).then(
                  function(response) {
                    data.push(response.data);
                    link = parse_link_header(response.headers()['link']);
                  }
             );
        }
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            // process functions
        });

        $scope.abc = abc;
        return abc;
        }
    );
}
```

Giving me async errors. I have referred to [Recursive $http.get in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354881/recursive-http-get-in-for-loop) but seems like different case. Seems like I need 1 promise resolved before calling to next one. Any idea for this recursive call please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but does a `while...in` loop even exist?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Why yes, yes it does

Comment: but the async call inside the synchronous while loop is the root of the problem here

Comment: @KevinB How should I correct it please?